# how to add nl2br function to sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I`m wondering, how to add function nl2br to my sidebar at WordPress.
Thing is, I add text widget to my sidebar and I want to change 'enter' to 
.

I know, that to register sidebar is code:

```
      register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Footer First', 'myTheme' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-5',
    'description' => __( 'Footer widget appears everywhere', 'myTheme' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

I was trying to add nl2br to before_widget, but it dont works... Probybly I need add function to my functions.php but I have no idea how to get content of my text widget.

Comment: This function just registers a sidebar, it has nothing to do with handling the actual _content_ that ends up in this sidebar. If you want to modify that content, then you should probably rather do that at the widget level.

Comment: At widget level? I use typical WP widget - text one. So where should I found content of it? I just want to have <br> if I use "ENTER" at this one...